# Search box and articles not showing in KOA Template

Tags: customer-community

We are creating a customer community based on the KOA template. However, I can only get my data categories, articles, and search box to show if I am logged in only.

I assume a community based on the KOA template can accessible to public, but that option isn't available in Preferences.

Lastly, I set my default data category visibility to "ALL" for the community.

What step(s) am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the detailed analysis of this issue

Created a community with koa template and here is what i initially got

[image]

Also no where in documentation SFDC indicates whether these templates are accessible for guest users or not .

I went to sites .Carefully note every community will have its own sites and since we are speaking about guest users we actually need to look into sites .

[image]

Click on your community site Label.Note that link is not highlighted .

Now i went to Public access settings .This is nothing but guest user profile.

Check the article types permission .Make sure you have atleast Read access .Also make sure the data category access is proper for guest users and your articles exposed to guest users and not just community.

[image]
[image]

Here is final screenshot on how it should look

[image]