# Articles not visible to Salesforce Community members

Tags: community, permissions, customer-community, articles

We have a private Salesforce Community built on Spring 16 Napili community template. Regular community members are not able to see articles. We followed the steps from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106469/search-box-and-articles-not-showing-in-koa-template) for the custom Customer Community profile these users are using, but this has not helped. That is, we have verified the profile has read access to the Article Type.

We have also made the data categories visible to this profile.

What else do we need to do to make the articles visible?

Comment: Did you check the customer check box for articles you published ?

Comment: Checking the customer checkbox solved the problem. Thanks again Mohith!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the data categories visibility. Also, check to see if the articles are published to the Customer channel.

Comment: Checking the customer checkbox solved the problem. Thanks Rob.

Answer (score 2):

Just Enable **Read Permission** in **Knowledge Base Permission** Section in **Customer Community Plus Login User** new profile.
You will see that Articles are now visible for guest users in community.
It worked for me.

Comment: You solved my issue, the profile had no read permission on the Knowledge object.

Answer (score 2):

I am so pleased to have found this post! I had exactly the same problem: could search for and view articles, but none were showing up in in navigational topics. As we have another Experience Cloud site using topics, I knew everything on a global level was correctly configured.

For me, it was the language configuration for this site that was the issue. I headed to Builder > Settings > Languages and ensured it was matched the value in Setup > Knowledge Settings > Default Knowledge Base Language.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Just a heads up that starting and/or ending with "Thanks" may make people think that this isn't an answer (note for reviewers: this does appear to be a distinct answer). The typical way to show appreciation on stackexchange sites (like this one) is to upvote things. You'll need 15 reputation to do that, and each upvote that you get (on a question or answer) gives you 10 rep.

Comment: I've also taken the liberty of formatting your answer slightly to make the solution you pose a bit easier to identify in a quick scan.